# D3.js linechart (v3) shows line and tooltip coordinates but the coordinate text sticks to screen even when moving mouse

Tags: javascript, django, svg, d3.js

I have code written in js d3. I have a functioning line chart and tooltip but the text sticks on the screen when moving the mouse and only large moves of the mouse remove the text. How do I fix it so that only the current coordinates show and when the mouse moves the old coordinates disappear?

code:

```
`
`            var foWidth = 300;
            var anchor = {'w': width/3, 'h': height/3};
            var t = 50, k = 15;
            var tip = {'w': (3/4 * t), 'h': k};


var fix_resize = 200;

// Set the color scale, if multi chart lines
var color = d3.scale.category10();

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right +  fix_resize,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom + fix_resize;


//var   parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
    function getDate(d) {
    return new Date(d.date);
    }


     var minDate = getDate(data[0]),
    maxDate = getDate(data[data.length-1]);

    var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);


    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().ticks(d3.time.months, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b %Y")).scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(6);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(6);

    // def the area under the line
    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.target_downside_base); })
        .y0(function(d) { return y(0); });

    // the charts line
    var linestroke = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")  //smooth line
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) ;})
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.target_downside_base); });x

    // the charts line , (2nd line)
    var cowenline = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")  //smooth line
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) ;})
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.cowen_base); })



    // Define an interpolated invisible line
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")  //smooth line
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.target_downside_base); });

     // group the data: draw one line per group
     var attackTypes = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {
          date: d.date,
          attackType: +d[name]
        };
      })
    };
  });

      // Adds the  canvas and axis properties
     var    svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");




    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.target_downside_base; })]);

    // Add the area under curve
    svg.append("path")      // Add the valueline path.
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
    .attr("fill-opacity", .1)
    .attr("stroke-width", 0)
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .attr("d", area(data));

     // Add the line , if area is also included then this must be separate
     svg.append("path")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
      .attr("stroke-width", 4)
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("d", linestroke(data));


     //2nd line
      svg.append("path")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
      .attr("stroke-width", 3)
      .attr("stroke", "darkred")
      .attr("d", cowenline(datacowen));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

     / Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

    // title
    svg.append("text")
   .attr("x", width/2)
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .style("font-size", "16px")
   .text("Target Downside - ATVI MSFT");

    // tried code: works and shows coordinates but text sticks for too long
    var focus = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .style("display", "none");
  var mouseLine = focus.append("path") // create vertical line to follow mouse
    .attr("class", "mouse-line")
    .attr("stroke", "#303030")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("opacity", "0.4");


  var tooltip = focus
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "tooltip-wrapper")
    .attr("display", "none");
  // append div tooltip
  var tooltip = focus
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "tooltip")
    .attr("class", "tooltip-wrapper")
    .attr("display", "none");

      var tooltipBackground = tooltip.append("rect").attr("fill", "#e8e8e8");

      var tooltipText = tooltip.append("text");


      var availableDates = data.map(item => item.date);

      function focusMouseMove() {
    tooltip.attr("hidden", null);
    var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    var dateOnMouse = x.invert(mouse[0]);
    //console.log("dateOnMouse" + dateOnMouse);
    // console.log(availableDates);
    // dateOnMouse.setMonth(0, 1);
    // dateOnMouse.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    //console.log(dateOnMouse.toString());
    //console.log(availableDates);
    //console.log("found " + availableDates.find(date => date === dateOnMouse.toString()));
    var nearestDateIndex = d3.bisect(availableDates.map(d => new Date(d)), dateOnMouse);
    var d0 = new Date(availableDates[nearestDateIndex - 1]);
    var d1 = new Date(availableDates[nearestDateIndex]);
    var closestDate;
    if (d0 < x.domain()[0]) {
      closestDate = d1;
    } else if (d1 > x.domain()[1]) {
      closestDate = d0;
    } else {
      // decide which date is closest to the mouse
      closestDate = dateOnMouse - d0 > d1 - dateOnMouse ? d1 : d0;
    }
    var closestDateConvert = closestDate.getTime();

    let chosenTargety;
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i].date === closestDateConvert) {
            chosenTargety = data[i].target_downside_base;
            break;     // Optional: break out of loop after finding desired targety
        }
    }


    var nearestDateXCord = x(new Date(closestDate));
    var nearestYCord = y(chosenTargety);

    mouseLine.attr("d", `M ${nearestDateXCord} 0 V ${ height}`).attr("opacity", "1");

    tooltipText.selectAll(".tooltip-text-line").remove();
    focus.selectAll(".tooltip-line-circles").remove();
    var formatTime = d3.time.format("%b %Y");



    // iterates through an object, nearestDateYValues, with the key of "Object.keys". It then creates a circle      

    for each corresponding y-value with its key as the color.
    var nearestDateYValues = { 'orange' : parseFloat(chosenTargety)};
    //console.log(nearestDateYValues['orange'].toFixed(2));
      //for (let key of Object.keys(nearestDateYValues)) {
    var fo = svg.append('foreignObject')
                        .attr({
                            'x': nearestDateXCord,
                            'y': nearestYCord,
                            'width': foWidth,
                            'class': 'svg-tooltip'
                        })
                     .text(`x: ${formatTime(closestDate)} \ny: ${chosenTargety}`);
                    var div = fo.append('xhtml:div')
                        .append('div')
                        .attr({
                            'class': 'tooltip'
                        })
                    div.append('p')
                        .attr('class', 'lead')
                        var foHeight = div[0][0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
                    fo.attr({
                        'height': foHeight
                    })



  };

  function focusMouseOver() {
    mouseLine.attr("opacity", ".5");
    tooltip.attr("display", "none");
    focus.selectAll(".tooltip-line-circles").remove();
    svg.selectAll('.svg-tooltip').remove();
    svg.selectAll('polygon').remove();
    svg.selectAll('foreignObject').remove();
  }

  function focusMouseOut() {
    mouseLine.attr("opacity", "0");
    tooltip.attr("display", "none");
    focus.selectAll(".tooltip-line-circles").remove();
    svg.selectAll('.svg-tooltip').remove();
    svg.selectAll('polygon').remove();
    svg.selectAll('foreignObject').remove();`
`
```

I tried moving around the focusMouse functions to differenet svgs but its no use. I tried the tooltip function but that didnt work. I would like to prioritize changing and debugging the current code so that it works properly.

[line chart with tooltip coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH58p.png)